# What baked good involves crushed digestives, peanut butter, and marbled chocolate?

Tags: baking

Recently i found a recipe for something I was interested in baking, but I cannot remember the name of it and my computer isn't accessible for a few weeks.
Can someone help me identify the name of the item being baked, or even point me towards something similar.

The recipe was along the lines of:

- Crush digestive finely
- Mix with peanut butter
- line baking tray

Then something was poured over the top and 'messed up' with a spoon to give  marble effect. (I assume chocolate)

Can anyone supply me with more details and suitable ways to find a recipe for this type of dessert?

Comment: Hi Terry, direct recipe requests are off topic here. But it is perfectly OK to ask for the name of a dish or more information which will help find recipes by yourself. I changed your last sentence so it won't invite people to start listing recipes, but to focus on the identification part instead.

Comment: Apple Mousse Cheescake: http://www.grouprecipes.com/129716/apple-mousse-cheesecake.html Local library probably has a computer you can use, or borrow a friend's cellphone for a few minutes.

Comment: 'digestive biscuits' are a typical substitution for U.S. graham crackers.  Searching on "graham cracker peanut butter" led me straight to peanut butter bars, which match your description : http://allrecipes.com/recipe/peanut-butter-bars-i/

Comment: Possibly some form of cheesecake, substituting peanut butter for the butter in the base?

Answer (score 1):

I made these Chocolate Peanut Butter Bars consisting of those ingredients and methods you talked about. Here is the link to a video demonstrating how to make this:https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PL0k8v-V15rKtQFicZQl4hcxldjvW7mbDH&v=GG581Dvf39w

Comment: We discourage link-only answers for a good reason: Imagine the link going bad or the original poster taking down the video. Now what information remains? The essential points should always *be right there n the answer itself*. Any links giving *additional useful information* are of course welcome.

Comment: @Stephie : In this case, the link provides supplemental information -- the answer is 'Chocolate Peanut Butter Bars'.